# How to assign default value to empty column

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am working on report builder 6i.

I have two tables

1- Company_info

2- Address_info

Comp_addr_code is a foreign key in company_info table which is primary key in
Address_info table.Now I am retrieving data from address_table base on comp_address_Code.But in some cases first three columns are empty in Address_info table.

I want for these columns 'X' should be displayed.What Changes should I make in my SQL Statement.My Sql statement is:

```
SELECT COMP_CODE, COMP_NAME, COMP_ADDR_CODE,
FROM COMPANY_INFO, ADDRESS_INFO
WHERE COMP_CODE=:P_COMP_CODE
      AND COMP_ADDR_CODE=ADDR_CODE
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `COALESCE`, it picks the first non-null value. I.e. if the column value is not null, return the column value, else return specified default value:

```
select coalesce(COMP_CODE,'X'),
       coalesce(COMP_NAME,'X'),
etc
```

Answer (score 0):

As given, only COMP_NAME can be NULL; if COMP_CODE or COMP_ADDR_CODE are null, those rows will not be in the resultset.

NVL or COALESCE are usually used to replace null values with other values, e.g.

```
SELECT 
COMP_CODE,
nvl(COMP_NAME, 'X')
COMP_ADDR_CODE
FROM COMPANY_INFO,ADDRESS_INFO
WHERE COMP_CODE=:P_COMP_CODE
AND
COMP_ADDR_CODE=ADDR_CODE
```